# Can I develop cross platform desktop applications that can run on windows, mac os x using visual studio 2015 and javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform, desktop

I need to develop cross platform application that can run on windows and mac using web technologies like html5,css and jquery. I am using visual studio 2015 as an IDE.

Comment: You might want to consider a native app instead of trying to use JavaScript or other web technologies for something like this. Xojo can make native desktop apps for Windows, Mac and Linux. http://www.xojo.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Xamarin Platfrom](https://xamarin.com/platform) to Create native iOS, Android,Mac and Windows apps in C#. It also has a Visual Studio plugin available that you can find [here.](https://xamarin.com/visual-studio)